# Elixir Phoenix: Strange "no function clause matching" error in Controller Test

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My tests for a controller are failing and I cannot figure out the root of this error. I tried everything I could think of and am a bit helpless since the error message is quite generic.

The error message in question (when running the tests).

```
1) test does not create resource and renders errors when data is invalid (MyApp.AdminControllerTest)
   test/controllers/admin_controller_test.exs:21
   ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in MyApp.AdminControllerTest.__ex_unit_setup_1/1
   stacktrace:
     test/controllers/admin_controller_test.exs:8: MyApp.AdminControllerTest.__ex_unit_setup_1(%{async: false, case: MyApp.AdminControllerTest, file: "~/MyApp/test/controllers/admin_controller_test.exs", line: 21, test: :"test does not create resource and renders errors when data is invalid"})
     test/controllers/admin_controller_test.exs:1: MyApp.AdminControllerTest.__ex_unit__/2



2) test creates and renders resource when data is valid (MyApp.AdminControllerTest)
   test/controllers/admin_controller_test.exs:12
   ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in MyApp.AdminControllerTest.__ex_unit_setup_1/1
   stacktrace:
     test/controllers/admin_controller_test.exs:8: MyApp.AdminControllerTest.__ex_unit_setup_1(%{async: false, case: MyApp.AdminControllerTest, file: "~/MyApp/test/controllers/admin_controller_test.exs", line: 12, test: :"test creates and renders resource when data is valid"})
     test/controllers/admin_controller_test.exs:1: MyApp.AdminControllerTest.__ex_unit__/2
```

**My Code:**

admin_controller_test.exs

```
defmodule MyApp.AdminControllerTest do
  use MyApp.ConnCase

  alias MyApp.Admin
  @valid_attrs %{email: "foo@bar.com", password: "s3cr3t"}
  @invalid_attrs %{}

  setup %{conn: conn} do
    {:ok, conn: put_req_header(conn, "accept", "application/json")}
  end

  test "creates and renders resource when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = post conn, admin_path(conn, :create), admin: @valid_attrs
    body = json_response(conn, 201)
    assert body["data"]["id"]
    assert body["data"]["email"]
    refute body["data"]["password"]
    assert Repo.get_by(Admin, email: "foo@bar.com")
  end

  test "does not create resource and renders errors when data is invalid", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = post conn, admin_path(conn, :create), admin: @invalid_attrs
    assert json_response(conn, 422)["errors"] != %{}
  end

end
```

admin_controller.ex

```
defmodule MyApp.AdminController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  alias MyApp.Admin

  plug :scrub_params, "admin" when action in [:create]

  def create(conn, %{"admin" => admin_params}) do
    changeset = Admin.registration_changeset(%Admin{}, admin_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, admin} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> render("show.json", admin: admin)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(MyApp.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
end
```

And finally parts of my router.ex

```
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  # [...]

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/api/v1", MyApp do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/admins", AdminController, only: [:create]
  end

  # [...]
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming from:

```
setup %{conn: conn} do
```

Change this to:

```
setup do
```

Comment: I'm confused, how does conn get referenced in the body of the setup block without the pattern match?

Comment: Yeah how is this accepted, conn is undefined.